# Rearrange multidimensional array with column values

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Here I have two multidimensional arrays. I have to combine them to make one multidimensional array. I tried but it is not happening. I don't know what I am doing wrong. I want to make `productId` as index, then values.

With this code:

```
$array1 = Array (
    "3" => Array ( "productId" => 3, "brandName" => "Honor" ),
    "4" => Array ( "productId" => 4, "brandName" => "Puma" )
);
$array2 = Array ( "5" => Array ( "productId" => 5, "brandName" => "Dell" ) ) 
$result = array_merge($array1,$array2);
print_r($result );
```

I get:

```
Array (
    "0" => Array ( "productId" => 3, "brandName" => "Honor" ),
    "1" => Array ( "productId" => 4, "brandName" => "Puma" ),
    "2" => Array ( "productId" => 5, "brandName" => "Puma" )
)
```

The above result is not my expected answer because `index` is automatically assigning. In my case, the index is `productId`.

**Expected Result:**

```
Array (
    "3" => Array ( "productId" => 3, "brandName" => "Honor" ),
    "4" => Array ( "productId" => 4, "brandName" => "Puma" ),
    "5" => Array ( "productId" => 5, "brandName" => "Dell" )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) is perfect for this situation. Just pass `null` for column key and `"productId"` for index key.

```
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
$final = array_column($result, null, "productId");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is expected with `array_merge`

> Values in the input array with numeric keys will be renumbered with incrementing keys starting from zero in the result array.

As you may have discovered, "numeric" also includes numeric strings.

It looks like your product IDs are already used as the array keys, so you should be able to get the result you want by using the [`+` (union) operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php#language.operators.array) instead.

```
$result = $array1 + $array2;
```